# Получить тип криптопровайдера по названию

Tags: c, winapi, криптография

В общем, стоит задача получить список криптопровайдеров, выбрать один и использовать его для шифрования. Список я получил через CryptEnumProviders(), а дальше нужно инициализировать контекст. Для этого нужно в параметрах указать тип провайдера, но я не могу заранее знать, какой будет выбран. Как я могу получить информацию о типе провайдера по его названию?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptenumprovidertypesa

Comment: @ori , то есть на этапе выбора запомнить индекс криптопровайдера и потом получить его тип?

Comment: Лучше почитать про BCrypt

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/